# How to run an R-script file within Kaggle

Tags: r, automation, data-science, kaggle

I have an R script file currently saved in my local computer. This is computationally intensive script which download data from Internet and save data in csv files in local disk.

I was thinking if I can run this script within Kaggle and save the data in csv files in Google drive. I also intend to run that script everyday at scheduled time.

Can you please guide me if this is a good idea to implement? How can I deploy this script in Kaggle and have it run based on scheduled time?

Your pointer will be highly appreciated.

s